# Xuggler screenRecording code affecting sound recording

Tags: java, audio, xuggle

I am working on an application for screencast with audio. screen recording with sound is working fine but the issue is that suppose I do recording of 5 mins then generated video file is of 5 min but generated audio file is of 4 min 45 sec. So basically the issue is that both audio and video are not in sync, audio file duration is less as compared to video file.

Both audio and video file recording are running in separate thread but still something is wrong.

VideoCapturing code:

```
public void run() {
    setVideoParameters();

    FRAME_RATE = frameRate;
    // let's make a IMediaWriter to write the file.
    writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(movieFile.getName());

    screenBounds = new Rectangle(RecorderSettings.m_CapRectX,
            RecorderSettings.m_CapRecY,
            (int) RecorderSettings.m_CapRectWidth,
            (int) RecorderSettings.m_CapRecHeight);

    // We tell it we're going to add one video stream, with id 0,
    // at position 0, and that it will have a fixed frame rate of
    // FRAME_RATE.

    // ScreenWidth && ScreenHeight multiplied by 3/4 to reduce pixel to 3/4
    // of actual.
    // writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_MPEG4,
    // screenBounds.width , screenBounds.height );
    writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, vcodec.getID(),
            (screenBounds.width * upperLimit) / lowerLimit,
            (screenBounds.height * upperLimit) / lowerLimit);

    // To have start time of recording
    startTime = System.nanoTime();


    while (isStopProceesBtnClk) {
        try {
            if (!isStopProceesBtnClk) {
                break;
            } else {
                synchronized (this) {
                    while (isPauseProceesBtnClk) {
                        try {
                            // catches starting time of pause.
                            pauseStartTime = System.nanoTime();
                            wait();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }


                BufferedImage screen = getDesktopScreenshot();
            // convert to the right image type
                  BufferedImage bgrScreen = convertToType(screen, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);


                // encode the image to stream #0
                if (totalPauseTime > 0) {
                    writer.encodeVideo(0, bgrScreen, (System.nanoTime() - startTime)- totalPauseTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                } else {
                    writer.encodeVideo(0, bgrScreen, System.nanoTime() - startTime, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);
                }




                // sleep for frame rate milliseconds
                try {
                    Thread.sleep((long) (1000 / FRAME_RATE));
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // ignore
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    try {
        writer.close();
        writer = null;
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore errors
    }
    // tell the writer to close and write the trailer if needed

}

public static BufferedImage convertToType(BufferedImage sourceImage, int targetType) {

    BufferedImage image;

    // if the source image is already the target type, return the source
    // image
    if (sourceImage.getType() == targetType) {
        image = sourceImage;
    }
    // otherwise create a new image of the target type and draw the new
    // image
    else {
        image = new BufferedImage(sourceImage.getWidth(), sourceImage.getHeight(), targetType);

        if (true) {
            int x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().x - 25;
            int y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().y - 37;

            Graphics2D graphics2D = sourceImage.createGraphics();// getGraphics().drawImage(m_MouseIcon,
            // x, y, 48, 48, null);
            graphics2D.drawImage(SimpleWebBrowserExample.m_MouseIcon, x, y,
                    48, 48, null);
        }
        image.getGraphics().drawImage(sourceImage, 0, 0, null);

    }
    return image;
}

private BufferedImage getDesktopScreenshot() {
    try {
        // Robot captures screen shot
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        Rectangle captureSize = new Rectangle(screenBounds);
        return robot.createScreenCapture(captureSize);
    } catch (AWTException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

AudioCapturing Code:

```
  public void run() {

        init();
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class,audioFormat,(int) (m_AudioFreq * sampleSizeInBytes));


        try 
        {
            m_TargetLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
            m_TargetLine.open(audioFormat, info.getMaxBufferSize());
        } 
        catch(Exception exp){
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }


    AudioFileFormat.Type targetType = AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE;

    try 
    {
        m_outputFile = new File(bufferFileName);
        while (m_outputFile.exists() && !m_outputFile.delete())
        {
            m_outputFile = BerylsUtility.getNextFile(m_outputFile);
        }

        FileOutputStream outFileStream = new FileOutputStream(m_outputFile);
        audioOutStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outFileStream,memoryBufferSize);
    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException fe){

        System.out.println("FileNotFoundException in VoiceCapturing.java :: " + fe);
    } 
    catch (OutOfMemoryError oe){

        System.out.println("OutOfMemoryError in VoiceCapturing.java " + oe);
    }

    while (isStopProceesBtnClk) {
        try {

            if (!isStopProceesBtnClk) {
                break;
            } else {
                synchronized (this) {
                    while (isPauseProceesBtnClk) {
                        try {                               
                            wait();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
                try 
                {
                    m_TargetLine.start();
                    int cnt = m_TargetLine.read(tempBuffer,0,tempBuffer.length);
                    if(cnt > 0){
                        audioOutStream.write(tempBuffer,0,cnt);
                    }

                } 
                catch (Exception e){                
                    System.out.println("Exception in VoiceCapturing.java :: " + e);
                } 
                /*finally{
                    finish();
                }*/
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    finish();
}


public synchronized void finish() 
{

    try 
    {
        System.out.println("AudioFinish");
        audioOutStream.close();
        FileInputStream audioInAgain = new FileInputStream(m_outputFile);
        long sampleBytes = m_outputFile.length();
        long sizeOfFrame = (long) m_SampleRate * m_Channels / 8;
        BufferedInputStream buffAudioIn = new BufferedInputStream(audioInAgain, memoryBufferSize);
        AudioInputStream a_input = new AudioInputStream(buffAudioIn, audioFormat, sampleBytes / sizeOfFrame);
        while (m_AudioFile.exists() && !m_AudioFile.canWrite()) 
        {
            m_AudioFile = BerylsUtility.getNextFile(m_AudioFile);
        }
        AudioSystem.write(a_input, m_targetType, m_AudioFile);
        buffAudioIn.close();
        m_outputFile.delete();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

could someone guide me on this...
Thanks.